# VertexList ordering of a simple graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a simple graph like

```
g=Graph[{b -> c, a -> b}]
```

I would like to have `f[g]` resulting in `{a,b,c}` but for instance
`VertexList[g]` results `{b,c,a}` which's not wanted.
Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: perhaps you can be more specific on f[]? Or is it a Sort of the vertexes?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have disordered graph

```
g = Graph[{b -> c, a -> b}]; VertexList[g]
```

> {b, c, a}

Use sort to find the order

```
f[g_] := Graph[Sort[VertexList[g]], EdgeList[g]];
VertexList[f[g]]
```

> {a, b, c}

If your graph is directed and acyclic, then you have a built in function to sort based on topological order:

```
TopologicalSort[g]
```

> {a, b, c}

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say the input data only contains edges. And the vertex doesn't limited to letters or numbers, the goal is to fine vertex ordering based on edges.

Comment: @jamtype7 See update.